# Access web service from GWT

Tags: gwt, soap, web-services

Is there any way how I can access a web service from GWT using its WSDL? Previously I was trying to use the generated classes from ws-import.... but then someone pointed out to me that GWT cannot handle all Java, just a subset of it, hence it won't understand the ws-import classes.

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Comment: What do you mean by "using its WSDL"?  Is the web service REST? SOAP? JSON? Something else? WSDL is just a language for describing web services AFAIK, not a web service format itself.

Comment: It's a SOAP service... sry for the misunderstanding

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 3):

GWT can access web services using a [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html), which makes HTTP calls to a service and then gets access to its response.

Since your web service is using SOAP, the response you get in your RequestBuilder's callback will be XML. Parse that XML to find the information you're interested in, and you're good to go.

Comment: Lol ok... that can kill me but anyways I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

In our project we were using Axis Client to make SOAP Web Service Call(WSDL Driven). We had use the inbuild plug tool provided by the WTP/ AXIS Webservice in Spring Source Tool to create the client using provided WSDL. We had use the same client code to incorporate with GWT and everything works fine.