# How to generate gwt classes from WSDL file

Tags: java, spring, gwt, cxf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GWT and WebServices (wsdl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600723/gwt-and-webservices-wsdl)

I have a project which contains Apache CXF web service and Spring 3.0 on the server side. I use gwt framework at client side and i want to call directly my web service from gwt. So i need a generator to generate gwt client side code from wsdl. Is there any solution or technic to generate gwt classes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in or supported standard solution for calling SOAP services from client side GWT.  You could look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556294/access-web-service-from-gwt) but there don't seem to be any easy answers.  The most standard and supported solution would be to develop a GWT server-side interface alongside your SOAP interface.